# EF6 + Postgres relation dbo.AspNetUsers does not exist

Tags: entity-framework, postgresql, asp.net-mvc-5

I have been following this post on using PostgreSQL with EF6 http://www.jasoncavett.com/blog/postgresql-and-entity-framework-6-code-first/.

I have started a brand new MVC5 project hoping to use Postgres in my application for backend.  The application starts up fine however when you go to register a user (I selected individual authentication) I get the following error messsage

> ERROR: 42P01: relation "public.AspNetUsers" does not exist

I am unsure as to how to resolve this problem.

The error happens on line 155 which can be seen [here](http://gyazo.com/5ad20d03f76b7136dc693ca32f056219)

More information can be provided if needed.

Answer (score 3):

I had ran the application before migrating to Postgres so all I needed to was to add a migration and update database through the package manager console.

Answer (score 3):

If you see this Error in 2018, the answer is because the table has not being added to the migrations.

> `dotnet ef migrations add 01_users` &&
>   `dotnet ef database update`

Answer (score 2):

It is interesting but when i write as below it works on tableplus;

```
select *
from "AspNetUsers";
```

or

```
select "UserName"
from "AspNetUsers";
```